# Работа Python 3.5 с JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, json-encode

Допустим, есть массив сообщений

```
{"out_read": 71621, "count": 30, "in_read": 71622, "items": [{"read_state": 1, "id": 71622, "date": 1457443154, "from_id": 260126670, "user_id": 260126670, "out": 0, "body": "11"}, {"read_state": 1, "id": 71621, "date": 1457443154, "from_id": 260126670, "user_id": 260126670, "out": 0, "body": "1"}, {"read_state": 1, "id": 71620, "date": 1457443154, "from_id": 260126670, "user_id": 260126670, "out": 0, "body": "11"}]}
```

Как обратиться к каждому элементу body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обращаться к элементам нужно, конечно, в цикле:

```
import json

json_text = '{"out_read": 71621, "count": 30, "in_read": 71622, "items": [{"read_state": 1, "id": 71622, "date": 1457443154, "from_id": 260126670, "user_id": 260126670, "out": 0, "body": "11"}, {"read_state": 1, "id": 71621, "date": 1457443154, "from_id": 260126670, "user_id": 260126670, "out": 0, "body": "1"}, {"read_state": 1, "id": 71620, "date": 1457443154, "from_id": 260126670, "user_id": 260126670, "out": 0, "body": "11"}]}'

data = json.loads(json_text)
for item in data['items']:
    print(item['body'])
# '11'
# '1'
# '11'
```